# How does one sum a whole column of datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a Datagridview in my C# program that contain numeric data.

I need to sum all column A  and all column B.

(I don't want to use any SQL queries.)

How Do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? What's the data source for the view?

Comment: i use Visual-studio 2008, FrameWork 3.5

Comment: check edited answer will resolve your issue

Comment: You have two options: summing on DataSource or summing on the bound Rows. Check my answer to see how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gridView.DataSource`. It can be either an [IList Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) or an [IListSource Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource.aspx) which has a method `GetList()` that returns an `IList`. So you can basically run a summing method on it's members.

Or if you know the exact type in DataSource, you can aggregate the data using specific methods of the object in there (even use the [Enumerable.Sum Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549046.aspx)  if possible).

or

```
decimal sum;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
  sum += (decimal)row[0].Value + (decimal)row[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Datagrid is bound to a DataTable, another option is to use the Datatable.Compute() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28VS.80%29.aspx

```
private void ComputeBySalesSalesID(DataSet dataSet)
{
// Presumes a DataTable named "Orders" that has a column named "Total."
DataTable table;
table = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];

// Declare an object variable.
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Total)", "EmpID = 5");
}
```